# Cannot get checkboxes after append

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, checkbox, append

I,ve made an script with dynamicly adding checkboxes. It works like this:

```
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async:false,
    url: base_url+"rapportage/get/leerlingen/coach/"+coach_id+"/",
    success: function(data){
      $.each($.parseJSON(data), function(i,item)
      { 
        $('.select-leerlingen ul').append('<li><input type="checkbox" class="leerling" name="leerling" value="'+item.id+'"> '+item.voornaam+' '+item.tussenvoegsel+' '+item.achternaam+'</li>');    
      });
    }});
```

After this action i try to index those checkboxes:

```
$('#submit').click( function(event) {

    var values_data = $('input:checkbox:checked.data').map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).get();

    var values_leerlingen = $('input:checkbox:checked.leerling').map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).get();       

    // Met AJAX naar de database doorvoeren
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async:false,
        url: base_url+"rapportage/saveForSession/",
        data: {data:values_data, leerlingen:values_leerlingen}
    });     
});
```

Sometimes it works fine. But on many occasions the variabele: values_leerlingen is empty when there are checkboxes checked. The dynamicly added checkboxes cannot be found anymore or something like that.

Does somebody know what i did wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Do not use `async: false`!

Comment: What do you mean by "*after this action*"? Where exactly did you put that code? And notice that none of the appended checkboxes is initially `:cecked`.

Comment: I,ve added some context. I need the checked array before the submit. At the backend the array is added to an PHP session.

Answer (score 0):

Editing my answer based on comments sorry .live() is removed from new jQuery
you can use 'on'

Comment: `Live` is deprecated per your own link. =)

Comment: .live() is  Deprecated

Comment: It was also for event handler bindings, which don't seem relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$(document).on('click','#submit', function(event) {

var values_data = $('input:checkbox:checked.data').map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get();

var values_leerlingen = $('input:checkbox:checked.leerling').map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get();       

// Met AJAX naar de database doorvoeren
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async:false,
    url: base_url+"rapportage/saveForSession/",
    data: {data:values_data, leerlingen:values_leerlingen}
});     
});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your reasoning for this?  Wouldn't you want the "indexing" function outside of the `$.each`, I don't think you need to reindex everything for each and every checkbox added.

Comment: Thanks for comment. But i need the array outside this request. I,ve added some context in my post.

Comment: updated my coment, you need to delegate the id as its not in the DOM on DOM-ready

Comment: Sorry, but the solution does not work. The #submit is triggert but the values_leerlingen array is still empty.